# Read debited amount from messages of inbox to calculate monthly expenses

Tags: android

I am working on an app which will calculate the expenses by reading the incoming messages of transactions.as so far I am able to get all the messages of expenses from below Code snippet

```
 if(cursor.getCount()>0)

    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            String s = cursor.getString(11).toLowerCase();
            if (s.contains("debited")) {

                count++;
                System.out.println("===body:" + cursor.getString(11));
                System.out.println("===count:" + count);

            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;

        }
```

output

```
Your a/c **** is debited INR 2000.00 on 22-11-2016 18:12:14 A/c Bal is INR **** Info: CASH-ATM/****

Your a/c **** is debited Rs 2000 on 2016-12-16 A/c balance is Rs **** Info: NEFT/MB/*****

A/c **** debited for INR 5000; ATM WDL. A/c Bal INR **** (incl. of uncleared chqs) as of 15JUN 13:43hrs
```

but not able to get the expense amount due to different SMS format followed by different banks.

Is there any way to get the exact debited amount?

Comment: Collects all the format of Bank sectors text message of Debit and analyze it.That will helps you to get it by exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Parama,collecting different messages format will be more tedious task and a tightly coupled dependency over banks message formats.Coz if bank is going to change their format then we have to revised that too in over app and that will be painful all the time to maintain app performance on play store.

Answer (score 0):

Split the message string using blank spaces(" ") into an array say array[].
Then check where each string in array contains only Numbers (1-9) and dot (.) using pattern matching.

The String with this pattern will be your debited amount . try this method.Hope this is one of the simplest method

Comment: Thanks Tomin for your reply, i have gone through this approach but in some messages there are account balance too ,in that scenario there will be confliction between debited amount and available amount

Comment: Search for the nearest word .Which is debited or balance. take the distance between the words. and the nearest one after occurring the word debited will be the debited amount

Comment: Ok, I will definitely going to try this and let you know.

Comment: Buddy, Somehow it is working fine in the case of double value but not working for integer amount debited, coz it is considering a/c no. too in case of an integer value.I am figuring it out...BTW Thanks, Tomin.

Comment: Can you please provide an example . Then I will try to sort it out. These 2 are different datas and not related. i hope they wont have any problem. That may the issue with the logic you had used. please try to find the error

Comment: Check for the very next double or integer value in the message after debted and before the work. for the first occurring integer check for word Acc or Account in the message before ocuurring that number. So who have to check for 4 distances at a time.

Comment: Your a/c 1234 is debited Rs 467 on 2016-11-22 A/c balance is Rs ****.** Info: NEFT/*****    Consider this message here i have debited amount in integer format not in double (no (.) separator) in this case i will get a/c no as a output which is wrong.

Comment: match for patterns which have digits and dots. never match for a pattern x.x . or match multiple patterns in a nexted if loop that is check for a pattern x.x or for pattern x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155985/discussion-between-santosh-yadav-and-tomin-b).